# In Oracle Apex 5.1, how do I return a value from a PL/SQL dynamic action on a button?

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

On an apex page, I have a button.  When the button is clicked I want to run a pl/sql procedure which generates a new user id, then go to a new page, passing that value.  I can call the procedure, but I don't know how to get the value it returns, and pass it to the next page...?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is better to do this in a process that submit the page. In this process you set the id value an item in your page. After you need to create a redirect that use this item to send the value to the other page.

1 - The button submit the page.

2 - You need a process to execute when page is submitted, this process set the value for an item.

3 - You need a redirect that use this item to send the value for the other page. The redirect is executed after the submit process.